# forecasting univariate time series with svm in R

Tags: r, regression, svm, prediction

I have a time series of 100 observations. I fit a svm regression model and I want to predict the value for y_{101}, but when I do it in R it returns 100 predictions, because it assumes I have 100 classifiers. How can I obtain one-step ahead forecast?

```
require(e1071)
y=cumsum(rnorm(100))
x=1:100
DF <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
svm(DF$y~DF$x,type="eps-regression",kernel="radial",cost=10000, gamma=10)
predict(aa, newdata=101)
```

Comment: `newdata=data.frame(x=101)` For `svm()` you can do: `aa <- svm(y ~ x, data=DF, ...)`

Comment: thank you jogo, but this it not what I wanted, it still giving me 100 values not just the value 101 that is that I want. Thank you

Comment: `aa <- svm(y ~ x,data=DF, type="eps-regression",kernel="radial",cost=10000, gamma=10); 
predict(aa, newdata=data.frame(x=101))` works for me (gives only one value). Your error is in not using `aa <- svm(y ~ x, data=DF, ...)` (as I recommended before).

Comment: Excellent! thank you very much!

Comment: @jogo, how would you add lags of the variable y for the svm model?

Comment: That is another question.